# What is the roadmap of hibernate-ogm regarding Criteria queries?

Tags: hibernate-ogm

I am considering migrating an application from hibernate/MySQL to hibernate-ogm/MongoDB. However my application relies heavily on criteria queries. I see that in 5.4.1 they are not supported yet. Does someone know what are the plans ahead for criteria queries? Should I convert to JP-QL or is it worth waiting for the implementation of criteria queries in hibernate-ogm?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have plans to implement Criteria at the moment.
I wouldn't wait for it.